# Combinatorial homework problem.

Tags: combinatorics

This is for homework so I don't want any solutions. Just some guidance.

Problem: Alice has $10$ balls (all different). First, she splits them into two piles; then she picks one of the piles with at least two elements, and splits it into two; she repeats this until each pile has only one element.

a. How many steps does this take?

b. Show that the number of different ways in which she can carry out this procedure is $$\binom{10}{2} \cdot \binom{9}{2} \cdots \binom{2}{2}$$

Comment: What is the effect of any single step on the total number of piles? How many piles are there at the beginning of the process?  How many are there at the end? I think all three of these questions are easy to answer, and putting the three answers together will solve the problem.

Comment: The vote to close this as off topic is absurd.

Comment: If she takes one ball from the pile at each step and puts it by itself, not in such a pile, then it takes nine steps, so the question is, will it take some other number of steps if she follows some other sequence?  My hunch is there's some elegant combinatorial way to show that the number of steps it takes doesn't depend on which choice of ways to separate them she makes at each step.

Answer (score 3):

HINT for (a): You can easily check by hand that:

- if she starts with $1$ ball, $0$ steps are required;
- if she starts with $2$ balls, $1$ step is required;
- if she starts with $3$ balls, $2$ steps are required; and
- if she starts with $4$ balls, $3$ steps are required.

This should suggest a hypothesis for the number of steps required when she starts with $n$ balls. It turns out that the hypothesis is correct and can easily be proved by so-called complete induction on $n$, the initial number of balls.

**Added:** Or you could use **Andreas Blass**’s hint in the comments; that approach is even easier and fits nicely with the following extended hint for (b).

For (b), let $a_n$ be the number of ways in which the procedure can be carried out when there are initially $n$ balls. Suppose that we add an $(n+1)$-st ball. Now when we carry out the procedure, we’re simultaneously carrying it out on the original $n$ balls, except that at some point we split out the new ball as a pile by itself. Consider any one of the $a_n$ ways to carry out the procedure on the original $n$ balls. We could

- split out the new ball first and then follow that way;
- follow that way for one step, then split out the new ball, and then go back to following that way;
- follow that way for two steps, then split out the new ball, and then go back to following that way;

and so on.

If we split out the new ball by itself when there are $k$ piles, it could be in any one of those $k$ piles. Thus, for each way of carrying out the procedure with the original $n$ balls, and each $k$ from $1$ through $n$, there are $k$ ways to carry out the procedure with $n+1$ balls. This means that each of the $a_n$ ways to carry it out with $n$ balls gives rise to $\sum_{k=1}^nk$ ways to do so with $n+1$ balls.

- Determine $a_2$ by actually counting.
- Show by induction on $n$ that $a_n=\binom{n}2\binom{n-1}2\ldots\binom{2}2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint for part b):  The procedure you've described is *reversible*.  If you want this fleshed out a bit further, look below.

> Count the number of ways you can start with all $10$ balls in separate piles and assemble them into one pile by coalescing things two piles at a time.  The first step can be done in $10\choose2$ ways.